# Find the matrix T relative to the standard basis $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $$T: P_2 \to P_2$$

Such that $$T(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2) = a_0 + a_1(x + 2) + a_2(x + 2)^2$$

Find the matrix $T$ relative to the standard basis $B$ for $P_2$: $$B = \{1, x, x^2\}$$

I understand the procedure for finding the matrix $T$, but how exactly do the vectors of $B$ plug into the equation? i.e $$T(1) = ?$$ $$T(x) = ?$$ $$T(x^2) = ?$$

Do we treat in the first example $a_0 = 1$ and in the second equation $a_1 = x$ and $a_3 = x^2$ in the last example?

Comment: The $a$’s are the *coefficients* of powers of $x$ in the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the result should be as follows, but I'm not sure?

$$T(1) = 0$$
$$T(x) = x + 2$$
$$T(x^2)= (x + 2)^2 = 4 + 4x + x^2$$

Which produces the matrix:
$$ [T]_\beta
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: $T(1) = T(a_0) = a_0$, where $a_0 = 1$, so...

Comment: And $T(x) = T(a_1x) = x + 2$ where $a_1 = 1$? And $T(x^2) = T(a_2x^2) = 4 + 4x + x^2$ where $a_2 = 1$?